# long text is truncated when passed to Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have got an external application(Serena Business Mashups), SBM is a business management tool and we are using as a defect tracker.

it has got a web service to do database operations.

I need to update a field on this system using their web service, the data I need to update is a long(110000 chars) string.

so when I invoke the update method, the data gets updated but it is truncated. I have pasted my web config setting below. So is there a limitation which I do not know?

I am using asp.net web services, not WCF.

thanks for your help.

Regards

`<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="aewebservices71" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00"
                 receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://imgtt1:80/gsoap/gsoap_ssl.dll?aewebservices71"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="aewebservices71"
             contract="BMService.aewebservices71PortType" name="aewebservices71" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue, it was because of the limitation of Serena Business Mashups web services.